# Python Pandas groupby: filter and apply according to condition on values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this pandas dataframe

```
interval_mins = {
    '10' : 0.11,
    '15' : 0.4,
    '20' : 0.19
}
pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : [10, 15, 20, 10, 20, 15],
    'interval' : [0.1, 0.39, 0.2, 0.12, 0.25, 0.42]
})
```

In pandas DataFrame, I want to select items with `interval` values less than `interval_mins` for each `id`, and then add to the next `interval` value of the same `id`.

Is there a way without using `for`?

Expected output:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : [10, 15, 20, 10, 20, 15],
    'interval' : [0.1, 0.39, 0.2, 0.22, 0.25, 0.81]
})
```

[image]

Comment: not clear ( items smaller than interval_mins ?) as to what is required, pls paste expected output

Comment: I do not think you example (in the image) is consistent with your rule, for id=20 you should add as well, since 0.22 > 0.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do:

```
m = df['interval'] < df['id'].astype(str).map(interval_mins)
df.loc[m.groupby(df['id']).shift(fill_value=False), 'interval'] += df.groupby('id')['interval'].shift()
```

**Details:**

Create a  boolean mask representing condition where `interval` values are less than `interval_mins` for each `id`:

```
print(m)

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

`groupby` the boolean mask `m` on `id` and `shift` downwards:

```
print(m.groupby(df['id']).shift(fill_value=False))

0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
```

`groupby` the dataframe on `id` and `shift` the `interval` column:

```
print(df.groupby('id')['interval'].shift())

0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3    0.10
4    0.20
5    0.39
Name: interval, dtype: float64
```

Use boolean indexing with `loc` to add the values corresponding to shifted mask:

```
print(df)

   id  interval
0  10      0.10
1  15      0.39
2  20      0.20
3  10      0.22
4  20      0.25
5  15      0.81
```

Answer (score 0):

Consistent with your rule, but not with your output (see my comment), this should do it. I leave intermediate calculations in place so it is easier to understand what's going on. Note I replaced keys in `interval_mis` with `int`s from `str`s. Desired output in column `interval_2`

```
df['add'] = df['id'].map(interval_mins)
df['add_cond'] = df['add']*(df['add'] > df['interval'])
df = (df.groupby('id')
        .apply(lambda d: d.assign(add_cond_shift=d['add_cond'].shift()))
        .fillna(0)
        .reset_index(drop = True)
    )
df['interval_2'] = df['interval'] + df['add_cond_shift']
df
```

produces

```
    id  interval    add add_cond    add_cond_shift  interval_2
0   10  0.10        0.11    0.11    0.00    0.10
1   10  0.12        0.11    0.00    0.11    0.23
2   15  0.39        0.40    0.40    0.00    0.39
3   15  0.42       0.40     0.00    0.40    0.82
4   20  0.20       0.22     0.22    0.00    0.20
5   20  0.25       0.22     0.00    0.22    0.47
```